# Stream story links not clickable

Tags: javascript, facebook

This started happening yesterday. Our app is both Website and Canvas. When our stream story contains links to our canvas app, the links in the story appear as-is. When the story links point to our website, facebook replaces the link with:

http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=qpp_id&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http://our-url/&response_type=code&display=page

This happens both in the story title and action links

What's more, the link is NOT clickable on facebook, apparently some onclick handler not registering.

Has anyone noticed anything similar, or what could it be? I am using the JS SDK without the "oauth:true" parameter (I have other problems with it, for another question)

Comment: In you app settings, on the authentication tab, is 'authenticated referrals' enabled? If yet, try turning this off.